# How do you write "(A OR B) AND (A OR C)" queries with Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I need to write a MongoDB query of the form "A OR B OR (C AND D)" to return some records.  We are using Mongoid for data access to our models.

I expanded that query to "(A OR B OR C) AND (A OR B OR D)" and was hoping that using Mongoid's Criteria method `any_of` like this: `Model.any_of(A, B, C).any_of(A, B, D)` would accomplish what I want, but that is expanded as "A OR B OR C OR A OR B OR D" before being sent to the database.

Is there a way to build this query, or do I have to build one query to do A OR B and another to do C AND D and take the union of them?

Answer (score 3):

(Edit: I just noticed this question is 3 years old. I have no idea why it just showed up.)

You want something like this:

```
Model.any_of(a, b, c)
```

Where `a`, `b`, and `c` are selector documents (which, remember, are ANDed with multiple clauses).

For example, if your queries are:

```
{a: 1}
{b: 1}
{c: 1, d: 1}
```

Then you would use:

```
Model.any_of( {a: 1}, {b: 1}, {c: 1, d: 1} )
```

This would generate a query like:

```
models.find({$or: [{a: 1}, {b: 1}, {c: 1, d: 1}]})
```

Comment: I started a bounty on this question because it's a good question without any good answers.

Comment: Aha, got it. Well, I hope mine is satisfactory. :)

Comment: How does `any_of` give you `(A OR B) AND (A OR C)` here?

Comment: The body of the question says "I need to write a MongoDB query of the form "A OR B OR (C AND D)"", which is what my answer addresses. The expansion is unnecessary to fulfill the original requirements.

Comment: Also, `(A+B)(B+C)` is the equivalent of `A+BC`, which is expressable via `any_of` as `any_of({a: 1}, {b: 1, c: 1})`.

Comment: (A OR B) AND (B OR C) isn't equivalent to A OR (B AND C). It's equivalent to B OR (A AND C), so it should be any_of({b: 1}, {a: 1, c: 1}).

Comment: The form given was `(A+B)(A+C)`, not `(A+B)(B+C)` - I made a mistake in my response comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this link, hope it might help you -

http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/

Probably if possible, you can combine ".any_in" and ".and" and check out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a bug in mongo, but I'm having a tough time figuring out where mongo issues are reported / tracked.

```
> db.things.insert({x : 1, y: 2});
> db.things.insert({x : 2, y: 3});
> db.things.insert({x : 3, y: 4});
> db.things.find( { $or : [{x:1,x:2}], $or : [{y:1,y:2}] });
{ ..., "x" : 1, "y" : 2 }
{ ..., "x" : 2, "y" : 3 }
```

Comment: Multiple `$or` statements don't make any sense. Think about what that'll be when converted to a BSON object. The latter will override the former. Addionally, your selector documents are guilty of the same failing; you're basically searching `$or: [{y: 2}]` there.

Comment: Multiple `$or` statements make perfect sense, it's just that they're apparently not supported by mongo (is there a link to verify this, btw?). It sounds like the best practice is to manually convert conjunctions of the form `(A OR B) AND (A OR C)` to disjunctions like `A OR (B AND C)` in order to use `$or`, since mongoid won't do this for us.

Comment: It makes sense in the boolean logic sense, but not in the JSON Object sense, which doesn't permit for duplicate keys. You are correct in that the DNF is the correct way to express the query.

Comment: Regarding supporting documentation for lack-of-support, See dwight_10gen's comments here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/cGfZXmaTZvo/zRT4crPaNi0J - while BSON could support multiple keys, it's designed to mirror the JSON spec, which precludes them, and driver implementations are frequently incompatible with duplicated keys, as well.